# Capturing core-transitionend from core-transition-css

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to use a core-transition-css element to slide a div offscreen and then capture the transition end event. In the code below the animation works but the callback never fires. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <link rel="import" href="../components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
  </head>
  <body fullbleed layout vertical>  
    <polymer-element name="test-app">
        <script>
            var transition;
            Polymer({
                ready: function() {
                },
                buttonClick : function() {
                    var target = this.$.myDiv;
                    var meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
                    meta.type = 'transition';
                    transition = meta.byId('core-transition-right');
                    transition.addEventListener('core-transitionend', this.animationComplete);
                    transition.setup(target);
                    transition.go(target, true);
                },
                animationComplete : function(e) {
                    alert('complete')
                }
            });
        </script>
        <template>
            <paper-button on-click="{{buttonClick}}">Animate</paper-button>
            <div id="myDiv" style="color: white; background-color: blue">It's a div</div>
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
    <test-app id="myTest"></test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that I made two mistakes in my example. The first was passing a boolean as the second parameter to transition.go(), it should be an Object with a boolean property named "opened".

Second, I put the event listener on transition instead of the test-app element.

Here's a working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="../components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
  </head>
  <body fullbleed layout vertical>  
    <polymer-element name="test-app">
        <script>
            Polymer({
                buttonClick : function() {
                    var target = this.$.myDiv;
                    var meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
                    meta.type = 'transition';
                    var transition = meta.byId('core-transition-right');
                    this.addEventListener('core-transitionend', this.animationComplete);
                    transition.setup(target);
                    transition.go(target, {"opened": false});
                },
                animationComplete : function(e) {
                    alert('complete')
                }
            });
        </script>
        <template>
            <paper-button on-click="{{buttonClick}}">Animate</paper-button>
            <div id="myDiv" style="color: white; background-color: blue">It's a div</div>
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
    <test-app id="myTest"></test-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

The animation happens and the event is captured. However, since paper-button also animates there are two core-transitionend events fired. Right now I don't see an easy way to distinguish between the two, though you can look at e.path. I will open a separate question for this.